# Display different combinations of values without large case/if statements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am what you would say is probably an intermediate, self-taught php coder. I have been having this issue with a few projects now as it's come up a few times and i cant seem to think of a good solution for it.

The problem i'm having is understanding how i can display different combinations of values pulled from an sql table without writing a huge case statement or a bunch of if's

Example below should shed some light on my issue:

```
    DATABASE:

    ID   NAME   STRENGTH    INTELLECT   AGILITY
     1   One       0           10         15
     2   Two      10            0         15
     3   Three    15           10          5
     4   Four     10           10          0
```

Once i query this data i place the values in some html like so and return it to the Javascript to be appended to its display container;

```
    $ItemBase = '
                  <div class="itemInfoContainer">
                    <ul>
                      <li><h1>'.$BaseValues["NAME"].'</h1></li>
                      <li>Strength: '.$BaseValues["STRENGTH"].'</li>
                      <li>Intellect: '.$BaseValues["ITEM_LEVEL_REQ"].'</li>
                      <li>Agility: '.$BaseValues["STRENGTH"].'</li>
                     </ul>
                   </div>';
```

My issue is i do not wish to display one of the stats of the item if it is 0, My example above only has about 3 possible combinations of the headings:Values that need to be displayed i could handle this with a simple set of if's or a switch statement like so.

```
    if ($BaseValues["Stength"] == 0)
     dont display strength
     display intellect & Agility
    else if($BaseValues["Intellect"] == 0)
     dont display Intellect
     display strength & Agility
```

Now let's say my data set can be displayed in 50 different combinations, surely making 50 if statements or a switch with 50 cases is not the best solution. I've seriously sat down and thought of a few different options but nothing has resulted in a viable method of executing this functionality. PLEASE HELP!!! please ask me to clarify if something is unclear i'm struggling with this and would resolve a huge headache for me.

Comment: Keep a mapping from the database column name to the "human friendly" label you want to use. Then for each row you can iterate through the columns and do basically the same thing for each column in each row: check the value, and if it's not 0 show the label and the value.

Comment: I should do a loop. In that loop I should display Items if Any Value is not zero. It requires a minor loop inside an outer loop.

Comment: @Pointy
Hi Pointy,

Thanks, this does seem to make more sense now, I'm assuming you mean to place those values in an associative array with key=>value, is this how you mean to keep a mapping of column name to human friendly?

Comment: you are saying whichever column has zero you don't want to show respective list item in your markup?

Comment: @JakeMcclay yes - basically, organizing some sort of keyed "index" for a list of related (but different and distinct) values is a good way of cutting down on cluttered code. The map can contain the label as well as (possibly) things like flags to say whether the value needs special formatting, or if special rules apply (like if there are some values that should be shown even when zero).

Comment: Ok perfect, this makes total sense to me now. Thank you so much!!